# Magento: What's the use of Mage_Core_Block_Flush (core/flush) block?

Tags: php, magento

It looks like this block directly flushes the output.

What's the practical use of this block?
How can I use it?

Did anybody ever use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not used by the core (afaik). It turns off output buffering, so the rendered output would be sent immediately. The only block where it would kind of work would be the root block, otherwise the nested `core/flush` block and all following blocks would be rendered before the containing outer blocks.

I can't think of a sensible use case. Since the front controller is responsible for sending the output to the client, the `core/flush` block breaks his process. In the worst case it could lead to PHP Headers already sent notices.

I don't know, but my guess is it is a relict from the pre-release days of Magento, where the whole rendering system wasn't finalized yet. Probably seemed like a good idea at the time.
Maybe someone who was with the core team at the time can enlighten us about the history.

Comment: Had never noticed the comment "To be used only as root". Hasn't changed since 1.0.

Comment: It's still in Magento2 by the way ... I opened a issue on GitHub for that: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35

Comment: It was removed from Magento2  ! https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35#issuecomment-7265641

Answer (score 1):

One case where it could be used is in custom reporting. I have some reports that take a long time to load due to heavy MySQL queries. I'm guessing that this block will allow me to start displaying the page as soon as output begins to generate, so that it doesnt have to wait for the phtml layout to complete its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the block is useless, because it was [deleted from Magento2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35#issuecomment-7265641).